# Linear algebra, inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices such that $AB = I$ then
>   $B$ is invertible and $A$ is inverse of $B$.

Basically can you help me prove the uniqueness of the inverse of matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Assume a matrix $A$ has two inverse matrices $B$ and $C$. Then,

$B=IB=CAB=C(AB)=CI=C$

QED.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $M_{n\times n}$ is invertible if (by definition) the exists a matrix $N_{n\times n}$ such that $MN=NM=I$ ($I$: Identity of ${n\times n}$).

Here you have $AB=I$, can you prove $BA=I$?

*NOTE:* This is how I interpreted your question, asking uniqueness of the inverse and that $A$ is the inverse of $B$ are different things.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is just a consequence of the fact that the inverse of a bijection is unique. If $AB=I$ then $B$ is injective as a linear transformation on a vector space. Being injective implies that it is surjective as well by dimension theorem. $B$ is thus a bijection and $A$ its unique inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that a matrix $A$ has a left (right) inverse $B$, then $A$ is invertible because we have
$$
X=IX=(BA)X=B(AX)
$$
hence
$$
AX=O\iff X=O
$$
which means that $A$ has left and right inverses. Now suppose that for some $B,C$, $AB=I$, and $CA=I$, then
$$
C=CI_n=C(AB)=(CA)B=I_nB=B
$$
So the right and left converses of a matrix are equal...
This proves the statement.